# Creating Java GUIs that resemble the native Windows look and feel

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

Is there a better package or external library out there that does a better job than `javax.swing` at resembling the native Windows look and feel? I want my Java GUIs to resemble the forms I create using C# and the .NET framework. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SWT comes closest because it actually uses the OS'es native widgets.
The downside is that you have to perform some memory management, which is not required with Swing.

Other options include QT with Java, more information on that in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422956/java-swing-or-java-qt

and wxWidgets with wx4j: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxWidgets

Comment: It's resource management, not memory management. Explicit disposal of external resources can be useful and need not be onerous.

Answer (score 7):

You can select the system look and feel with swing :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Set System L&F
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
    catch (InstantiationException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
       // handle exception
    }

    new SwingApplication(); //Create and show the GUI.
}
```

---

**Resources :**

- [Oracle.com - How to Set the Look and Feel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)
- [Substance project](https://substance.dev.java.net/)

**On the same topic :**

- [Good-looking Java Swing Look&Feel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559559/good-looking-java-swing-lookfeel)
- [How to improve look and feel of JAVA swing GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592207/how-to-improve-look-and-feel-of-java-swing-gui)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into [setting the look and feel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html); if you use the Windows look and feel, your app will look more like a native app.

See [this comparison](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/plaf.html) of the various look and feels.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind spending some many [JIDE](http://www.jidesoft.com/) is a great product which offers as well 'windows' look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

Try SWT which is the GUI widget toolkit of Eclipse. A disadvantage of SWT is that it has some platform dependent libraries for each platform SWT supports: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/