# How can I create a "modern looking" Java desktop application?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel, swingx

Similar questions to this are asked periodically, but many of these answers are outdated.

I need to build a cross-platform desktop application in Java with a GUI of comparable quality to contemporary desktop apps.

Swing is the default choice, but I have yet to encounter a Swing application that didn't look, at the very least, quite dated and clunky (subjective, I know, but with GUIs it's hard to avoid aesthetic judgements).

I notice that the new Bitcoin client now uses QT with Java bindings, and does have an attractive user interface, but this has the disadvantage that it is no-longer pure Java.

So much of what I find when I search for Swing-related libraries is 5 years old or older, even though the aesthetics of desktop applications have evolved significantly since then.

If you needed to build a Java desktop application from scratch, what would you use for its GUI?

Comment: I don't think the question will survive but...

Comment: This question is inappropriate here, as it asks for discussion and opinion. The FAQ specifically mentions discussion type questions as being a poor fit for the Q & A format of SO. If you have specific programming questions, please ask them and we'll try to help. Conversational questions don't work well here, as they can't be definitively answered. Thanks. :)

Comment: Ken, I don't agree.  Not every question has a black-and-white answer, and if SO is limited to the questions that do have a black-and-white answer, then it will be significantly less valuable.  In general I think that people are far too eager to close questions here, given that the harm caused by a false positive (a question that was closed that shouldn't have been) is far greater than that caused by a false negative (a question that should have been closed but wasn't).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look into changing the Look and Feel of your Java program.  This allows you to customize the overall "theme" of your program.
[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) is information on changing the LAF.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that - do you have any specific recommendations about good modern LAFs for Swing?

Comment: I personally prefer the GTK LAF.  Here are a couple other nice looking ones: http://dlemmermann.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/the-best-swing-look-feel-bizlaf/.

Answer (score 29):

I can also offer you a new LaF to look into - [WebLaF](http://weblookandfeel.com). I'am currently working on it to bring a lot of UI features and make work with Swing much easier for anyone by just using WebLaF library basic features.

A few examples showing how some of WebLaF components look like:
[image: Some of WebLaF components]

Some of main goals i am targeting:

1. Great and modern-looking L&F with support for all Swing components
2. An extensive set of additional components which you won't find in standard Swing
3. A big set of Utility classes to assist you with writing the code

WebLaF library also suggests a few other advantages and unique features:

1. It is an open-source project (GPLv3 licensed)
2. Easy components styling using painters system (specifically with 9-patch files)
3. Quick and easy customization of the default "Web" style
4. Lots of features to accelerate and simplify Swing application interface creation

You can try the [demo-app](http://weblookandfeel.com/downloads/weblookandfeel.jnlp) to see if it is modern and simple enough :)

Comment: your the best this LAF is great :)

Comment: Absolutely beautiful piece of work Mikle, you are to be commended.

Comment: +++ top of L&Fs, please to ignore - but have to do something with getPreferredSize (one constant for whole L&F applyied for all JComponents) and gap v.s. alingment for Standard LayoutManagers (sure who cares about)

Comment: @mKorbel didn't really understand what you mean. Preferred size with WebLaF acts the same way as it does without it, WebLaF just provides a few addittional options to configure it. And i didn't do anything about standard layout managers - WebLaF uses almost the same layout style MetalLookAndFeel does with just a few small improvements, as i recall, and doesn't change any layout-related stuff. Though i might be missing something - would really love to know if there are actually any bugs presented :)

Comment: interesting info, you are overrode MetalLookAndFeel, maybe to corresponded to my comment about non_proportional painting on the screen, my question is do call doLayout (few small improvements, as i recall, and doesn't change any layout-related stuff), I'll post a comment with printcreen when I'm play with your L&F in next time

Comment: Amazing! And high quality demo too!

Answer (score 12):

I've had good experiences with [FlatLaf](https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/).

It's easy to install, it's cross-platform, it has no external dependency, it's open-source (Apache license), it includes dark modes and there are tons of [themes](https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/themes/).

[image: light]

[image: dark]

After adding :

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel( new FlatLightLaf() );
```

your app looks like it was written during the last decade, and not during the previous millenium.

It also has one high-contrast theme, for accessibility.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. FlatLaf looks very convincing.

Comment: @MWiesner: You're welcome. It was a pleasant surprise, since Java GUIs tend to come with 90s look otherwise. It's still in development, and 2.0 looks promising.

Answer (score 11):

Have you looked into [JavaFX 2.0](http://javafx.com/)? It is designed to interop easily with Swing, and has many modern 'good looking' controls.

Also, as lrAndroid mentions, a Swing app can look like a native app if you set the system look and feel with:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Answer (score 5):

Modern Javascript frameworks (ExtJS, Dojo, etc...) offer the same widgets richness or more (Excel like grids for instance), a wider variety of L&F and usually fit better with the OS of the user. 
Users are also very comfortable with their browsers and, hey, "modern stuff" is on the web, and the modern web today is HTML+Javascript.

The overhead of converting an app to "web like" is minimal. An embedded Jetty can remain really small and disk space has become much less of an issue.

There are additional benefits going down this route for the future evolutions of the application.

- Suddenly, the desktop app becomes a server app, which can be accessed from another desktop. We were able top promote a desktop app to 'portal' in a matter of weeks.
- Rewriting the app in terms of (Ajax) web services provides an easy transition to creating a full REST (or SOAP...) services stack. The app can then be integrated to other applications, easily monitored externally, etc...
- Support of other devices (smart phones, tablets,...) becomes much easier, by concentrating on the UI layer only
- As the app grows, separation of concerns is cleaner; developers working on the UI do not have to mess with low level code.
- There are a lot of excellent JS/HTML designers and developers that do not program in Java.

**EDIT**

3 years later this has become extremely easy thanks to [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/)

Comment: How do you handle launching the web browser in a cross platform way? Can you cite some examples of modern desktop apps using the web browser for their UI?

Comment: With Java 6+ `Desktop.getDesktop(  ).browse( new URI( uriString ) );`

Comment: ..which you may associate with a `TrayIcon`. If your app is running in the background, the UI can be 'shown' by clicking on the icon and performing the call above again.

Comment: Modern applications: using the browser for local apps is what is behing Adobe Air and HTML 5 storage (Google ditched its application when HTML5 came along with similar functionalities).

Comment: interesting ideas... By chance do you know of some products which took this approach to desk top apps?

Answer (score 3):

Try one of these:

1. [JTattoo](http://www.jtattoo.net/)
2. [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/)
3. [Quaqua](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/)

Answer (score 1):

What about Nimbus look and feel? [Oracle Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/otherFeatures/nimbus_laf.html)
Also take a look at [SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559559/good-looking-java-swing-lookfeel)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but if you don't want to use FX and still want to use Swing, then try [MacWidgets](https://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/wiki/Examples), i've used it on a couple projects. It's very light, and looks great. Below is an old project i was working on, over time i've perfected using macwidgets and now use it internally in my company.

http://www.digitalhand.net/projects/jdataanalyzer/mainGUI.png

Answer (score 0):

QT is quite extensive but also very big (bloated) and complex. There is also the SWT library being used by open office for instance. SWT uses native UI widgets for buttons, tables etc where as Swing emulates them.

However, the trend is clearly towards writing rich client applications for the browser using HTML and Javascript. Both of these have made huge strides in the past few years.

HTML5 specifically targets rich client applications with features such as better forms and local database to support disconnected scenarios (note that this last feature is not standardized yet but it is implemented by all latest browsers).

Javascript has now powerful libraries with jQuery and its many plugins. There are even languages like Coffeescript which can be used to produce Javascript with a simpler and more powerful syntax.

There's also no need for such apps to connect to an outside server. Small footprint local servers (eg: jetty, node.js, ...) and databases (SQLite, H2,...) can be installed on the client to make a completely self contained application.

Comment: Can you provide any examples of modern desktop apps that have web-based UIs?  I know [Freenet](http://freenetproject.org/) does it, but it's hardly an example of good UI design :-/

Answer (score 0):

Go for [Jetpack Compose for Desktop](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-desktop/). It's a super modern reactive UI which is nice to work with. It also works the same as it would for Android with very few exceptions. It's Kotlin though instead of Java, but these are both JVM based and it's very easy to make the jump.