# How to personalize TextField design with Swing

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to let the textField of eclipse/swing this way?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a matt look to the border of text field like this :

```
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
// left side border        
    textField .setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 5, 0, 0, Color.BLACK));
//right side border
    textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 5, Color.BLACK));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to customize only  Inputfield, extends JTextInputField and Override the paint() method.

But probably you will need a full [Look and Feel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134516/how-can-i-create-a-modern-looking-java-desktop-application)